# how to filter html with jquery picnet table filter

Tags: jquery

I have the [picnet table filter](http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm) setup and its working! But i have one colunm in my table that contains links. The default filter only filters the text inside the `<a>` for this example its 26.
Any way to get it to filter the data-content attribute from the links. So that i can type in zshare.net and not '26' to get the rows that contain it to show up?

If not is there any plugin like this i can do this with.

```
<td><a rel="popover" data-content="10upload, 2shared, badongo, crocko, depositfiles, extabit, fileape, filedropper, filefactory, filesmonster, zshare.net" class="btn btn-mini listpop" data-original-title="Supported mirrors according to website">26</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textbox").keydown(function(){
    var t=$(this).val();  
    $("#table tr") .show();
    $("#table tr td a") .not("a[data-content *="+t+"]").parent().parent()  .hide();
 //parent().parent()= <tr> tag
});
```